# Not able to view Data Source in Tableau

Tags: rest, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am trying to upload and download data sources using REST requests in tableau.

I created a Project (`new-project-by-mayank`) > Workbook (`Test-1`) and uploaded a Data Source (`Blobcsv.csv`).

[image: Tableau Dashboard]

Now I am making a REST request through POSTMAN to list all the data sources on my site but I see only one data source which was initially there, not the `Blobcsv.csv`

[image: Screen Shot of POSTMAN request]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the Explore level view? Your GET seems to only be returning your Sample project so I'd like to see the hierarchy you have for your projects. Also, are you using the user credentials or token method for login? I recreated this using tokens and it returns all of my data sources regardless of project hierarchy.

Comment: Also, this may be an instance where Tableau does not recognize a csv as a data source but as an external file.